# ASP.NET MVC Uploads and Downloads, Using IIS to control MIME Types?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, web-config, mime-types

In short, is there a way to get an MVC Upload ActionResult & Download FileResult to respect web.config's forbidden MIME types?

I see a few solutions knocking about mostly focussed on hard-coding for MIME type inside the ActionResult by examining HttpPostedFileBase on upload and serving MIME type on download, but I am looking for a much more elegant approach. Hard-coding, or even re-inventing the wheel with appsettings seems silly.

I have put the following into web.config to no avail:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="*.exe" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />    
</httpHandlers>
```

MVC just does not respect IIS' configuration on MIME types and hoes its own road, which is frustrating. Does anyone know of a better way using config to accomplish this with ASP.NET MVC? Otherwise, I will probably resort to an Action Filter with appsettings to control it, or similar.

Download code, simply to show method of serving the files:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Downloads the document.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="documentId">The document identifier.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ActionResult DownloadDocument(int documentId)
    {
        ActionResult actionResult = null;
        InternalClient internalClient = null;
        Document document = null;
        ContentDisposition contentDisposition = null;
        try
        {
            internalClient = new InternalClient();
            document = internalClient.GetDocument(documentId);

            contentDisposition = new ContentDisposition
            {
                FileName = document.FileName,
                Inline = false,
            };

            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition.ToString());
            actionResult = File(document.FileBytes, document.ContentType);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            exception.Log();
        }
        finally
        {
            internalClient.TryDispose();
        }

        return actionResult;
    }
```

Comment: Try the same on the System.webServer->handlers that's where I have my file extensions handlers.

Comment: I just did without success, sadly. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Its a wild guess but since you mentioned MVC, I'm guessing that you're probably running IIS7+. In that case, `httpHandlers` won't matter since they work only for IIS6 (or IIS7+ classic mode).

To stop IIS7+ from serving a file with a specific extension, try this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".exe"/>
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

This will cause the site to return a `404.3` error as shown below:
[image]

To make it return `403`, use this (verified)

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="ExeFile" verb="*" path="*.exe" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

[image]

Comment: Is it only `exe` that you're having trouble with? Can you try some other extensions like `jpg`? That'll give you an idea if something else is interfering/overriding.

Comment: Also make sure you have this: `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />`. W/o this, IIS will handle it and your app won't have a chance to do anything.

Comment: Great shout on the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests, that had slipped my mind, but it is set to true. Looks like I'll end up writing an Action Filter at this point. Sucks... thanks for the ideas.

Comment: P.S. I'll update this Q if I come across a config fix.

Comment: Gave you the bounty as a measly token for your time. Thanks again.

Comment: I'll try to replicate this on my local box. With IIS, things are usually tricky.

Comment: I'm so sorry, my previous answer didn't have the right configuration. I verified my updated answer in both IIS and IISExpress. `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` was not set, but even with setting that, the results were same.